# Pending tests in Jest?

Tags: mocha.js, jestjs

Does Jest offer any sort of "pending test" like those in Mocha?

Mocha's [pending tests](https://mochajs.org/#pending-tests) let us write  placeholder tests which are helpful when designing a test suite:

```js
describe('pending tests', function() {
  it('should be a real test someday');
});
```

Pending tests aren't converted by [jest-codemods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-codemods) and pass through unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Since the answers above were given this has changed. `.skip` is technically not a pending test. Jest now provides `test.todo("description")` without the callback to declare a test is yet to be written ([ref](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testtodoname)).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `skip`:

```
describe('pending tests', function() {
  it.skip('should be a real test someday', () => {});
});
```

I believe you can also use this on describe (`describe.skip`).

Comment: This doesn't work. Running the tests throws this error: `encountered a declaration exception` with this info: `Missing second argument. It must be a callback function.`

Comment: Updated answer to include callback

Comment: It works for me; e.g., `test.skip( 'foo bar', () => {} );`